# Outputing values from a laravel list in blade

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a laravel list defined in my controller as follows:

```
$industries = Industry::lists('id', 'name');
$salaries = Salary::lists('id', 'range', 'rate');
```

How do I output or access the columns in blade templating?

I do the following and I get error 'trying to get property of non object':

```
@foreach ($industries as $industry)
<div class="checkbox margin-top-0  ">
  <label>
    {!! Form::checkbox('industry_list[]', $industry->id) !!}
    {{$industry->name}}
  </label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

How can I iterate using a for loop as well as I'm trying to determine the first iteration - using the below i get offset error.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <= count($salaries); $i++)
<div class="checkbox @if($i == 0) margin-top-0 @endif ">
  <label>
    {!! Form::checkbox('salary_list[]', $salaries->id) !!}
    {{$salaries->name}}
  </label>
</div>
@endfor
```

And how do I iterate the $salaries array - do i need to make it a collection since `Salary::lists('id', 'range', 'rate');` array only contains two columns and strangely when i do 'dd($salaries);` why is the array defined with the 'range' value as the key and the 'id' as the value despite it being declared with 'id' being the key?

```
array:33 [
 "10,000 - 15,000" => 24
 "15,000 - 20,000" => 25
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you understood `lists()` a bit wrong. First of all, it builds an array, and arrays have a *key* and a *value*. There's no room for a third attribute, and the `lists()` function therefore only takes two arguments:

```
public function lists($column, $key = null)
```

Also, the first argument is the *value* and the second one is the *key*. This is due to the fact that you can also build an array with numeric keys only.

So you should do this instead:

```
$industries = Industry::lists('name', 'id');
```

And then, in your foreach loop you don't have to treat it like an object, it's just the value:

```
@foreach ($industries as $id => $industry)
    <div class="checkbox margin-top-0  ">
        <label>
            {!! Form::checkbox('industry_list[]', $id) !!}
            {{$industry}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

---

However, in your case I don't really see the benefit of using `lists()`. Just retrieve the full model collection with `Industry::all()` and you can do things like `$industry->id` and `$industry->name` and you will be able to handle more than just two values.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$industries = Industry::all('id', 'name');
$salaries = Salary::all('id', 'range', 'rate');
```

> static Collection|Model[] all(array $columns = array('*'))
>
> Get all of the models from the database.
>
> Parameters array  $columns
>   Return
>   Value Collection|Model[]

reference: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html